# Проблема кириллицы в URL при помощи urllib.request

Tags: python, url, кириллица, urllib, python-3.5

После выполнения кода:

```
import urllib.request

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Запорожье')
```

компилятор выдаёт целую тираду с ошибкой "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 35-37: ordinal not in range(128)"

Латиницу распознаёт. Пробовал и encode и decode и никак не получается побороть.
Python 3.5, который полностью должен "поддерживать" unicode.

Comment: Добавьте это в ответ

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 7):

Можешь использовать urllib.parse.quote() для кодировки части URL содержащей UTF-8.

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse   import quote

url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + quote('Запорожье')
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил с помощью [`urllib.parse.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import urllib.parse

api_key = 'key...'
addr = 'Запорожье'
base_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'address':addr ,'key': api_key})

url = base_url + params
```